# SharePoint 2007 and WebDav pro's & con's & custom development

Tags: 2007, webdav

recently I've heard about WebDav and that is being used with SharePoint. I did some research about WebDav, read some topics on Internet etc etc.

What I've understood that WebDav is is an extension of the HTTP that facilitates collaboration between users in editing and managing documents and files stored on World Wide Web servers.

But I don't understand where SharePoint comes in? SharePoint is by itself a collaboration system which stores and manages the documents, I don't really understand how the WebDav comes in help with already good SharePoint features.

So if the connection for SharePoint goes through WebDav, what does it then mean? And for example if I create some extension for document libraries for example extra feature which on document add will fill or add an extra document, will this WebDav prohibit it?

It is more an open question, if anyone could give me info on this WebDav or more helpfull links on it, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The following page explains how you can use WebDAV and make sure you watch the video:
http://barracudadrive.com/FileServer.lsp

Comment: Can you tell me, for example if someone uses the webdav with document library in sharepoint and i make some custom development, for example to prohibit on crreating folders in document library will it have any effect on working with webdav?